# How to delete a specific folder in a workspace in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to remove one folder from a Jenkins project, I know you can wipe the whole database but I don't know if I want to do that, it's a node e2e testing program, so I'm afraid it will wipe the dependencies.

Is there a way to delete just one folder in Jenkins? Or am I being irrational thinking if I wipe the database, it will break the job?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean that you want to delete a folder during your build? Do you know in advance the path to this folder?

Comment: @Luc yeah I do, i guess I could just run a shell command to remove that folder, if thats what you were getting at.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I would have done! using absolute path.

Comment: nice, that would have been a good fix as well!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention like I said above, this is a node e2e tester, I wiped the workspace and ran npm install as a shell command.

This worked, your dependencies will remain, just make sure you run npm install as one of your commands before running your job.

Thanks!